# How Do I Add A Pause/Wait Interval After Every Tap?

Tags: java

I would like my method `tapBack()` to have an interval of 1sec after every tap.

*Problem:*

The method tries to tap way to fast and causes test failures.

```
public static void tapBack(int times) {
    logger.info("Trying to go back..");
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        tapBack();
```

Comment: You can use `Thread.sleep(1000)`

Comment: @pahan Thanks for the reply, can you show me how `Thread.slee`' would be implemented into my code? Thank you

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < times; i++){
        tapBack(); Thread.sleep(1000);}`  Calling Thread.sleep(1000) would halt the current thread for 1 second.

Comment: @pahan Perfect, thank you! I definitely over thought this one. Appreciate the help.